# Tomcat Processing Time

Tags: tomcat, process

in my Server Manager at

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/status
```

I can see

```
Max processing time: 4069 ms Processing time: 108.345 s
```

I cant quite grasp what this time is telling me? I apologize. I realize this is a very basic question, so kindly point me to a resource where I can acquire basic Tomcat knowledge such as this.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Max processing time is the maximum time it can take to process one request by the servlet.

Processing time is the total time it took to process all requests by the servlet.

As for a resource you can acquire knowledge about Tomcat metrics, try this: [Apache Tomcat Metrics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e10115/middleware_apache_tomcat.htm)